# How can I wire my case fans to be powered by my PSU and not motherboard?

Tags: power-supply, cable, wiring, molex

My case fans are plugged into my motherboard and I have no more slots for fans.  I read from a source on yahoo answers I should wire all my case fans to a molex 4 pin adapter--and plug that directly into the power supply.

The problem is my PSU doesn't have a Molex insert or adapter.  [This is my power supply.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182188)

It has what looks like to be PCI-E plugs coming out of my PSU.  How can I route my case fans to connect to my PSU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PSU definitely has such connectors, they look like this (from wikipedia):
You just have to put your fans on adapters like [these](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812201009)  are (probably come with your fans) and from there to your PSU.

[image]

Comment: I don't see those on my PSU though.  Did you see the newegg link I posted?

Comment: @Kyle yeah, on the link they are called "6 x 4-Pin Peripheral Connector"

Comment: @Kyle - I can't see from the pictures very well, but I've NEVER seen a modular power supply that didn't come with at least one Molex power cable chain, and that one clearly comes with a lot of cables.  The reviews seem to indicate that it includes Molex as well.

Answer (score 1):

Get a SATA to Molex adaptor

then you can plug your fan in